# PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg, OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

В ходе применения периодически всплывает исключение: System.OutOfMemoryException

Из-за чего может возникать проблема переполнения памяти?

[image]

Comment: А какого размера картинка? Сколько таких картинок вы обрабатываете? Может, память и вправду исчерпалась?

Comment: В среднем 4 картинки каждая весом примерно 1.5 мб. Исключение выплыват переодически, обычно на 5 - 7 раз при заходе на эту страницу.

Comment: На стеке посоветовали выставить доп параметры, вроде норм работать стало, без исключений:

WriteableBitmap wb = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(Stream, 250, 160);

Comment: А не течёт ли у вас память? Попробуйте залогировать [состояние памяти](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Может быть, старые ненужные картинки всё ещё находятся в памяти?

Comment: Проверил сейчас, в нутри метода поместил этот код:

MessageBox.Show(((long)GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / (long)1048576).ToString() + " Mb");

Право дело - не пойму где может быть утечка =(

Comment: Попробовал вот так:



      private void PhoneApplicationPage_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PhotoPanel = null;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }

Не помогает.